# .Net Maui Collectionview frame with label issue

Tags: label, frame, preview, collectionview, maui

I was wondering if anyone else is experiencing this issue with the latest .Net maui preview(Version 17.2.0 Preview 1.0)

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding EventList}" x:Name="Events_CollectionView" ItemsLayout="VerticalList"  SelectionMode="Single">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <Frame>
                                        <StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Seconds}" FontSize="35" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

This displays the seconds of my countdown and gets updated every second. The result:
[image]

You can see the edge of the screen and where it gets cut off.
Here is an example when the frame is removed leaving just the stack layout in the data template:
[image]

Edit:
It appears not to just apply to frames but when I have a stacklayout inside of a stacklayout in the collectionview it appears to produce a similar result.

Comment: No problem here when i reproduce it with your CollectionView with just numbers , maybe the problem is in here . *This displays the seconds of my countdown and gets updated every second*. Maybe show how you update it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71346801/maui-updating-collectionview-event-countdown?noredirect=1#comment126160830_71346801

Comment: A bit hard to tell , can you put a small example of your project on Github ( as Public repository ) so we can download it and check what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that adding a width request to the Label allowed the full text to be displayed.